# How to use SimpleRNN to model a modulus function & predict many to many sequence

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have designed this toy problem to understand the working of `SimpleRNN` in Keras.

My input sequence is:

```
 [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
[(0+x1)%2,(x1+x2)%2,(x2+x3)%2,(x3+x4)%2,(x4+x5)%2)]
```

My code is:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
def generate_sequence():
    max_len = 5
    x = np.random.randint(1,100,max_len)
    shifted_x = shift(x, 1, cval=0)
    y = (x + shifted_x) % 2
    return x.reshape(max_len,1),y.reshape(max_len,1),shifted_x.reshape(max_len,1)

X_train = np.zeros((100,5,1))
y_train = np.zeros((100,5,1))
for i in range(100):
    x,y,z = generate_sequence()
    X_train[i] = x
    y_train[i] = y

X_test = np.zeros((100,5,1))
y_test = np.zeros((100,5,1))
for i in range(100):
    x,y,z = generate_sequence()
    X_test[i] = x
    y_test[i] = y

from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(3,input_shape=(5,1),return_sequences=True,name='rnn'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=70,
          epochs=200,verbose=0,validation_split=0.3)

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

When I train this `SimpleRNN` I only get an accuracy of 50%, each item in the sequence only depends on the previous item. Why is the RNN struggling to learn this?

```py
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step
Test score: 0.6975522041320801
Test accuracy: 0.5120000243186951
```

UPDATE:
It turns out mod function is very hard to model, I switched to simple data generation strategy like y[t] = x[t] < x[t-1], then I could see the model performing with 80% binary accuracy.

```py
def generate_rnn_sequence():
    max_len = 5
    x = np.random.randint(1,100,max_len)
    shifted_x = shift(x, 1, cval=0)
    y = (x < shifted_x).astype(float)
    return x.reshape(5,1),y.reshape(5,1)
```

So How do i model a mod function using a RNN?

Comment: If the operation was "/2.", I think the network would learn it quite easily (test that). But since you're using "%2", your net should be a little more intelligent than a single layer. (Please confirm this by testing)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition. What additions would you suggest to make this network good enough

Comment: I don't know anything specific, but maybe a lot of layers with more units.]

Comment: I tried changing to "/2" and final layer to just Dense without activation, used mse as loss. Still no luck, it wont learn anything

Comment: @DanielMöller please check the update in the question